# Java: Access external variables (defined in a Project File)

Tags: java, eclipse, class, variables

I'm using Eclipse to develop a Java Application.
It is possible to define a variable in a File (a '**.properties**' file, for example) that belongs to my project , and call it in my class?

In this case, I want to execute a loop 'X' times, and that number 'X' should be defined in that File.

Comment: You want to know how to load/read from properties file?

Comment: You should take a look to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Comment: @SatheeshCheveri I didn't say that I want exactly to load/read from that kind of Files, because I don't know if it is the best option. But if it is possible, yes, it is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Ofc you can. You only have to read that file from your Class and parse the line with your variable. Here you have an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/) of how to read a file.

Comment: But my file belongs to my project, it is in my src/main/resources/ folder. What is the path to that? Do I have to write the all path to my project folder (C:/...) ? Or there is another way, since it belongs to my project?

Comment: No, just **src/main/resources/fileName**.

Comment: Thanks. What I really wanted was the @hveiga answer, with that path.